# cakephp form helper select box with selected value

Tags: cakephp

I am using the cakephp form helper. Basically I want to output a select box with 2 options, public and private. I want private to be selected by default. Does anyone know how to get the private option selected by default? This is what I have so far:

```
echo $this->Form->input('profile', array(
    'type' => 'select', 
    'options' => array('public' => 'public', 'private' => 'private'), 
    'selected' => 'private'
));
```

The private value isn't selected though

Thanks

Comment: you should not use "selected" - see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/07/cakephp-beginner-tips/ for details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried your code and it works nice. "Private" appears selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, 'public'/'private' maps to a tinyint(1) in the database and therefore shows a checkbox by default. That is why you had to include 'type' => 'select'.

If that is the case, you can specify the index, as in 'selected' => '1'.